# Configuring hilo "could not get or update next value[SQL: ]"

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to configure NHibernate to with hilo generator, but the following configuration throws a GenericADO exception saying "could not get or update next value[SQL: ]". If the generator class is 'identity' it works as expected.

Note. I set the "Is Identity" to 'No' on the SQL Server end when using the hilo generator.

```
<class name="Model.Session, Domain" table="Session">
  <id name="SessionID" column="SessionId" type="Int32">
    <!--<generator class="identity" />-->
    <generator class="hilo" /
  </id>
  <property name="SessionToken" column="SessionToken" type="String" length="80"/>
  <property name="UserID" column="UserId" type="Int32"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the table that NHibernate uses to get the "low" values from the server has not been created, either manually or by schema generation.

> The basic idea is that you have two
>   numbers to make up a primary key- a
>   "high" number and a "low" number. A
>   client can basically increment the
>   "high" sequence, knowing that it can
>   then safely generate keys from the
>   entire range of the previous "high"
>   value with the variety of "low"
>   values.

Comment: can u please point me to a place where hilo configurtion is explained e.g tables need to be created in the SQL server.

Comment: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator. If creating manually, you must also add a row with the initial value.